# How can i prevent my bot from getting roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

guys I'm working on a reaction role discord bot but whenever I set a reaction my bot gets the role too How can I prevent that? I don't want my bot to get every role

this is my code rn.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
for role_id, msg_id, emoji in client.reaction_roles:
  if msg_id == payload.message_id and emoji == str(payload.emoji.name.encode("utf-8")):
   await payload.member.add_roles(client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_role(role_id))
```

edit:
so I added an if statement to my code but apparently it's wrong. so can you tell how it's working??

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  for role_id, msg_id, emoji in client.reaction_roles:
    if msg_id == payload.message_id and emoji == str(payload.emoji.name.encode("utf-8")):
      if payload.member== client.user:
        return
      else:
        await payload.member.add_roles(client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_role(role_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, ignore the case where the reaction adder is your bot!

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
   if payload.user_id = client.user.id:
       return
   #other stuff here
```

Comment: Comments aren't really a place to ask a new question. post a new question or edit this question if it is relevant.